# Return values from function with pdo try/catch

Tags: php, pdo

I have a php function much like this:

```
function add($db, $value) { 
    try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(value) VALUES (?);");
    $stmt->execute(array($value));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
         // Error handeling
    }
}
```

If the query is successfull and there is no exception, shouldn't the function return TRUE?

The only way to get the function above return TRUE is if I modify the "try" section:

```
if ($stmt->execute(array($value))) {
return TRUE;
   }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your question now?

Comment: My question is: shouldn't the function return true

Comment: My question is if the "if" section really should be nessasary. Shouldn't the function return TRUE anyway?

Comment: If you don't make a return statement the default is `null`! (And yes you need the if because the code can 'success', but the query can fail)

Comment: And it may be useful to return something useful from the 'catch' section to indicate there was a failure. 'Throw' the error again is normally sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php):

> If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned.

Since `NULL` is evaluated as false in most contexts, then the answer is no, this function will not return `TRUE` unless you **explicitly** state it. E.g.:

```
function add($db, $value) { 
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(value) VALUES (?);");
        if ($stmt->execute(array($value))) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        // Error handeling
    }
    // If we got here, the execute did not succeed
    return FALSE;
}
```